# Find FaceBook Friends friend using c# facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to find friends friend of user in using c# facebook SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends

"You can read the list of a User's friends by issuing an HTTP GET to /PROFILE_ID/friends with any valid access_token of the current session user."